# Generate openapi model and interface from folder instead of file

Tags: java, maven, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have multiple *.yaml files. I want to generate models and interface using maven. Is it possible to point multiple files or folder instead of single file in single execution. Here is my maven configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bookApi</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/books.yaml
                        </inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <modelPackage>com.mhaque.bookstore.model</modelPackage>
                        <apiPackage>com.mhaque.bookstore.controller</apiPackage>
                        <configOptions>
                            <java8>false</java8>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>studentApi</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/students.yaml
                        </inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <modelPackage>com.mhaque.bookstore.model</modelPackage>
                        <apiPackage>com.mhaque.bookstore.controller</apiPackage>
                        <configOptions>
                            <java8>false</java8>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I want something like:

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bookstoreApi</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/books.yaml,
                            ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/students.yaml
                        </inputSpec> <!--multiple files or folder-->
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <modelPackage>com.mhaque.bookstore.model</modelPackage>
                        <apiPackage>com.mhaque.bookstore.controller.v1</apiPackage>
                        <configOptions>
                            <java8>false</java8>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: can you elaborate why you have split the specifications?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: You can use an external tool such as `yaml-merge` or `yq` to create a merged YAML file.  For example:

```
yq m books.yaml students.yaml > all.yaml
```

(You should arrange that the combined "all.yaml" file is written to the project's "target" tree.)

Answer (score 0):

you are right to use the `<interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>` configuration, in your `<inputSpec>` you can write your openapi.yaml file that contains your $refs to other files